# Need to refresh Chrome twice after Angular recompile

Tags: angular, google-chrome, browser, page-refresh

(I considered putting this on SuperUser but it's really more a programming question)

I'm using a grunt browsersync task in the background that recompiles my angularjs code whenever it detects a change. My angular is written using ES2015, and transpiles through the grunt task using Babel. Every time, after the transpile is complete, I have to do a hard CTRL-F5 in Chrome to see the changes take effect. In my Chrome developer tools I have the 'Network > Disable cache' option checked. Why do I need to refresh twice and is there a way to only have to refresh once *without* manually clearing the cache first or having to use some kind of hack?

Comment: Caching behaviour is controlled by web server. The problem isn't specific to Angular or any other client-side thing. If you expect that a server won't cache scripts, you misconfigured it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure this could help, but I have similar problem which I resolve by adding some random string behind the src of my script

```
//to tell the browser it's a different script
<script src="myscript.js?id=123123121"></script>
```

so that the browser identify it as a different script; I have work with either gulp, jspm, webpack and the way I implemented the above code is by using a plugin which will rewrite the script with Date.now() on each compile

Comment: Thanks John, I'm looking for a cleaner way to fix this though rather than having to hack things.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow It's valid way to handle this case, especially in production. Where 'id' can be file timestamp or build #. This will refresh scripts for both end users and devs while keeping browser cache enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the issue was that I was loading my page using a direct URL in a separate browser tab, rather than the tab which grunt browsersync is connected to using its designated port number (I need to do this because some of my page components are dependent on the port number, so I need to control this). After the grunt transpile, I need to wait until the browser reload of the connected url is complete before I refresh my page in the other tab, then I see the refreshed code first time.